# Sort sublists from a list and then saving them as sublists

Tags: python-3.x, list, append, sublist

```py
b = np.array([[1, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],[1, -22, -5.9432,-4.0916],[1, -20.559, -5.4188, 
-4.0916],[1, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],[2, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],[1, -20.559, -5.4188, 
-4.0916],[3, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],  [2, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],[1, -20.559, 
-5.4188, -4.0916],[5, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],[1, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],[3, -20.559, 
-5.4188, -4.0916],[7, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],[1, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],[7, -20.559, 
-5.4188, -4.0916], [5, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],[2, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],])

list1 = b.tolist()
len(list1)
myList = []
mynew = []

for j in range(8):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
            if list1[i][0]==j:                
                myList.append(list1[i][0:4])  
            mynew.append(myList)
print(myList)
```

**My output should look like:**

```
[[[1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [1.0, -22.0, -5.9432, -4.0916], [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916]], [[2.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [2.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [2.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916]], [[3.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [3.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916]], [[5.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [5.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916]], [[7.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [7.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916]]]
```

**What I am getting is :**

```
[[1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [1.0, -22.0, -5.9432, -4.0916], [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [2.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [2.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [2.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [3.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [3.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [5.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [5.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [7.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [7.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916]]
```

**ANY HELP would be appreciated.**

Comment: Hello, would a numpy split of list into equal parts help? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html

Comment: No. Because, I do not know the size. I will use the code for a big list, where I won't be sure about the range of the values in the first column. Although I am using range(8) but I will change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a temp `jList` to store all the list that the 1st element is the same.

```py
for j in range(8):
    jList = []
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[i][0] == j:
            jList.append(list1[i][:])

    if len(jList):
        myList.append(jList)


from pprint import pprint
pprint(myList)

"""
[[[1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],
  [1.0, -22.0, -5.9432, -4.0916],
  [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],
  [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],
  [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],
  [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],
  [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],
  [1.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916]],
 [[2.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],
  [2.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916],
  [2.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916]],
 [[3.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [3.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916]],
 [[5.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [5.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916]],
 [[7.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916], [7.0, -20.559, -5.4188, -4.0916]]]
"""
```

But you can also do that with pandas

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(b)

result = []

for (method, group) in df.groupby(0):
    result.append(group.values.tolist())

pprint(result)
```

Despite grouping all the same 1st element into one list, you can also sort their places by the 2nd, 3rd and 4th elements with [pandas.DataFrame.sort_values()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by putting the following lines before `groupby`

```py
df.sort_values([0, 1, 2, 3], axis=1, ascending=[True, True, True, True], inplace=True)
```